# Getting function using GMP

Tags: c++, func, gmp

I have point(x,y) and i want add another point. i write only formul, but i want getting function:

```
    struct point {
        mpz_t x;
        mpz_t y;
    };

    point my_func(mpz_t x, mpz_t y) {
   /..../
        //lambda
        mpz_sub(a, Y, y);
        mpz_sub(b, X, x);
        mpz_invert(c, b, P);
        mpz_mul(b, a, c);
        mpz_mod(f, b, P);

        //point x
        mpz_mul(a, f, f);
        mpz_sub(b, a, x);
        mpz_sub(c, b, X);
        mpz_mod(d, c, P);

        //point y
        mpz_sub(a, x, d);
        mpz_mul(b, f, a);
        mpz_sub(c, b, y);
        mpz_mod(e, c, P);

        return (x, y);
    }
```

It seems to me that this should not be difficult, but I have been driving all day.
point gp = {x, y};
*error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer*

I want only having a point (x, y) to get the next point at the output. it does not have to be a structure, I tried pair and tuple, it still does not help.

Comment: Why don't you use boost multiprecision? It has a nice C++ wrapper for GMP.

Comment: I read that boost uses gmp and decided to use it right away.
I'll try boost, but I'm sure it will take me a whole day (.

Comment: > `return (x, y);` That won't work. `return {x, y}` is possible though

Comment: Without going to boost, GMP itself comes with a C++ interface (header gmpxx.h, type mpz_class). You cannot return a mpz_t (or an aggregate of mpz_t), it doesn't have value semantics, either you need a C++ wrapper, or you can pass a reference/pointer to a point to the function and assign to it inside the function (then you don't need to return anything).

Comment: Marc Glisse, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really, why bother with something if i need to just change the values ​​of x and y
the void function by reference solved the problem, I am grateful for the useful advice
this function working and need RAM 600kb

```
void add(mpz_t& x, mpz_t& y, mpz_t& X, mpz_t& Y,  mpz_t& P) {
    mpz_t a, b, c, d, f;
    mpz_inits(a, b, c, d, f, 0);
        //lambda
       mpz_sub(a, Y, y);
       mpz_sub(b, X, x);
    mpz_invert(c, b, P);
       mpz_mul(b, a, c);
       mpz_mod(f, b, P);
        //point x
    mpz_mul(a, f, f);
    mpz_sub(b, a, x);
    mpz_sub(c, b, X);
    mpz_mod(d, c, P);
        //point y
    mpz_sub(a, x, d);
    mpz_mul(b, f, a);
    mpz_sub(c, b, y);
    mpz_mod(f, c, P);
        //set x, y
    mpz_set(x, d);
    mpz_set(y, f);

    mpz_clears(a, b, c, d, f, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mpz_clear the variables. Also, you can simplify `mpz_t& x` to `mpz_t x` in the function arguments, because mpz_t already acts like a pointer/reference (that's why you couldn't return it). I still recommend you use a C++ wrapper, it is so much more convenient to write `b=a-x;` and not need the init/clear for each variable.

Comment: Yes, I turned on cleaning at the end of my function, but if I run it sequentially in a loop, I see how the amount of RAM grows, as soon as the loop ends, the memory is cleared. While not yet solved this problem.

Comment: If the numbers get progressively bigger and bigger, it is normal that they take more RAM (and the iterations get slower).

Comment: I understand this, of course, yes
but in my case I write:mpz_clears(a, b, c, d, f, NULL);
and then immediately after i call mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, a);
and see that these variables are not cleared!

Comment: I tried to clear each variable separately (mpz_clear(a);), but it still does not help.

Comment: It does `free` the memory, but that doesn't mean that the memory is immediately overwritten or returned to the OS, see many questions about `free` on this site.

Comment: I apologize for the tediousness,
I changed my response code,
and in the comments I indicated that it outputs after clearing temporary variables a, b, c, d, f.maybe I'm doing something wrong or does the ump library work incorrectly for me?
after cleaning (mpz_clears(a,b,c,d,f, NULL), where I explicitly specify NULL, I still see the values of temporary variables.